# MySQL 8.0.26 How to Improve Multi-Table Statistics Query Efficiency

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have an internal statistics page for my admins to show information on individual sites and their traffic. The query takes anywhere from 1,500ms to 2,400ms to run, and I would like to get this under 500ms or lower if possible.

The `ORDER BY` is dynamic inserted into the statement based on user input from the Admin.

- table_sites.site_id ASC/DESC
- table_sessions.session_count ASC/DESC
- table_profiles.profiles ASC/DESC

The results must include a site, the site must have a session, however it does not need any profiles which accounts for the `LEFT JOIN` on `my-db.profiles`.

**MySQL Query**

```
SELECT *
FROM
  `my-db`.`sites` AS table_sites
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT
    MAX(`site_id`) AS 'site_id_b',
    COUNT(`session_id`) AS 'session_count',
    MIN(`session_datetime`) AS 'first_session',
    MAX(`session_datetime`) AS 'last_session'
  FROM
    `my-db`.`sessions`
  WHERE
    `session_datetime` > (NOW() - interval 7 DAY)
  GROUP BY
    `site_id`
) AS table_sessions ON (table_sites.site_id = table_sessions.site_id_b)
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    MAX(`site_id`) AS 'site_id_c',
    COUNT(`site_profiles_id`) AS 'profiles',
    SUM(`origin`) AS 'profiles_originated',
    SUM(`scanned`) AS 'profiles_scanned'
  FROM
    `my-db`.`profiles`
  WHERE
    `date_added` > (NOW() - interval 7 DAY)
  GROUP BY
    `site_id`
) AS table_profiles ON (table_sites.site_id = table_profiles.site_id_c)
WHERE
  table_sites.`site_id` IN ( table_sessions.site_id_b )
ORDER BY table_sessions.session_count DESC
LIMIT 25;
```

**Query EXPLAINED**

[image: MySQL Query EXPLAIN]

**Sites Table**

```
CREATE TABLE `sites` (
  `site_id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `account_id` bigint NOT NULL,
  `site_hash` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `site_address` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `site_status` int NOT NULL,
  `site_created` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `site_updated` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`site_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `site_hash_UNIQUE` (`site_hash`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

**Sessions Table**

```
CREATE TABLE `sessions` (
  `session_id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `site_id` bigint NOT NULL,
  `profile_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `session_hash` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `session_ip_address` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `session_useragent` text CHARACTER SET utf8,
  `session_page_uri` text CHARACTER SET utf8,
  `session_datetime` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `session_has_data` tinyint DEFAULT '0',
  `session_processed` tinyint DEFAULT '0',
  `session_queued` tinyint DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`session_id`),
  KEY `session_has_data` (`session_has_data`,`session_id`),
  KEY `session_processed` (`session_processed`,`session_id`),
  KEY `session_queued` (`session_queued`,`session_id`),
  KEY `session_datetime` (`session_datetime`,`session_id`),
  KEY `session_hash` (`session_hash`,`session_id`),
  KEY `site_id` (`site_id`,`session_id`),
  KEY `profile_id` (`profile_id`,`session_id`),
  KEY `session_data_processed_queued` (`profile_id`,`session_has_data`,`session_processed`,`session_queued`,`session_id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `session_page_uri` (`session_page_uri`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

**Profiles Table**

```
CREATE TABLE `profiles` (
  `site_profiles_id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `site_id` bigint NOT NULL,
  `profile_id` bigint NOT NULL,
  `origin` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `scanned` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_added` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `date_lastseen` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`site_profiles_id`),
  KEY `site_id` (`site_id`,`site_profiles_id`),
  KEY `date_added` (`date_added` DESC,`site_profiles_id`),
  KEY `origin` (`origin`,`site_profiles_id`),
  KEY `scanned` (`scanned`,`site_profiles_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Comment: Does the  condition in the outermost query's `WHERE` clause (`table_sites.\`site_id\` IN ( table_sessions.site_id_b )`) affect the results in any way? Wouldn't the inner-join condition between `table_sites` and `table_sessions` (`table_sites.site_id = table_sessions.site_id_b`) ensure the condition is always true?

Comment: @outis You are correct, removing it retains the same result. It was redundant. After 15 tests, no change in performance after removing it.

Comment: Would you post an updated query & query plan, and add query statistics from the performance schema? What are the table statistics for `sessions`? Looking at the existing plan, there doesn't seem to be much room for improvement; I've a sneaking suspicion it would take something like sharding (MySQL Cluster?) or some other advanced DBA technique; this might require the expertise of the folks on [DBA.se].

Answer (score 0):

You have aggregating subqueries on your `sessions` and `profiles`. On `sessions` you use

```sql
 WHERE session_datetime > (NOW() - interval 7 DAY)
 GROUP BY site_id
```

An index on `(session_datetime, site_id)` will probably help this query. The query planner can run an index scan in the appropriate order for the grouping. Considering you want to join on `site_id` you might also try an index on `(site_id, session_datetime)`. After you create those two indexes, EXPLAIN will tell you if it chooses either one. Then drop the one it doesn't use.

The same reasoning applies to `profiles(date_added, site_id)`.

Comment: @o-jones I tried adding the new KEY `site_id_session_date` (`site_id`,`session_datetime`), but it still favors KEY `session_datetime` (`session_datetime`,`session_id`).